# ngrx/store after action/effects UI notification

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am using ngrx/store and ngrx/effects.

This is the flow,

1. user click login button
2. LOGIN Action dispatched
3. $effects perform http.post credentials for login
4. dispatch LOGIN_SUCCESS or LOGIN_FAILURE Action

**Question**: I would like to perform some UI task, eg, pull down the modal, or show a pop up of the error message, after the action.

How would I go about subscribing to the response in my component?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your state should have a flag that would notify your component that it should do an action.

Something like this:

State:

```
const initialState: SomeState = {
    loggedIn: false,
    ...
};

export default function(state = initialState, action: Action): SomeState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case StateActions.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {loggedIn: true});
            ...
```

Then in your component you subscribe to the state and if `loggedIn` is true you know that you should for example show the modal.

Another approach would be to perform the task right in your effect through a service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  A follow up question: What if say, I am updating user's profile.  I send an USER_UPDATE Action, but I would grey out the 'Save', and once the save operation is completed, I re-enable it.

What should I be 'observing' ?

Comment: In your state you create a `loading: boolean` param which is `false` by default. The `USER_UPDATE` action sets it to true, then you should have a `USER_UPDATE_COMPLETE` action which is called (through an effect) after the update is complete and it sets the `loading` back to false. You can optionally create an access function in your reducer and listen to that, something like this: `(state$: Observable<SomeState>) => state$.select(s => s.loading)`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Yep... on my page's ts, I have an ng-if/ng-class based on the s.loading.  Thanks again!